# toc links point to wrong pages

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, tableofcontents

i have a simple tex file. when i compile it with `$ pdflatex test.tex` it generates a pdf. the table of contents has clickable links but they don't work!
the page numbering is correct, but when i click a line it directs me to the wrong page.

has anyone an idea how i can fix it?

here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[autostyle=false,german=quotes]{csquotes}  %% for \enquote{}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\title{test}
\author{me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section[]{Abstract}
blabla bla
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\part{part1}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section[]{Abstract}
\section{sec a 1}
bla bla
\subsection{sec a 1.1}
bla blub
\section{sec a 2}
\newpage
\part{part2}
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\section[]{Abstract}
\section{sec b 1} % the toc entry for this section points to page 1 but it is on page 2
blub blub
\section{sec b 2}  % the toc entry for this section points to page 1 but it is on page 2
blub blub
\subsection{sec b 2.1} % the subsection in the toc points to the right 2nd page!

\end{document}
```

and here you see the toc. as you can see, the mouse over hint tells that the link points to page 1 but the number on the right says it is on page 2.

[image: wrong link]

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you reuse a [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) counter that could make its way into a link, duplicate hyperlinks occur. Visually this is fine, but internal to the document, the jumps are ambiguous. So, you need to provide `hyperref` some help.

The *easiest* way to circumvent this problem and provide `hyperref` some assistance is to add to your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thepart.section.\thesection}
```

after loading `hyperref`. The above prepends `\thepart.` to the `hyperref`-related `\section` link. Since the re-use of `\section` counters is based on your use of `\part`s, this addition will make for a unique link and remove ambiguous destinations.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. I ll try it todays evening when i am back home and accept the answer if it works for me.